# Have I lost my ripple

Tags: ripple

I was hoping someone could help me please?

I used to have a desktop wallet for XRP which I just found out had been deleted and that’s where my coins were.

Is there anyway to access those coins again?- I am unable to download that desktop wallet since I cannot find it- id really appreciate any help.

Comment: You need to edit your question to include information about what back-ups you had, if any. For instance, if you wrote down your *ripple secret* (string of letters and numbers beginning with *“s”*), you would be OK. If your wallet gave you a *seed phrase* & you wrote it down, you would be OK (once you'd figured out which  type of seed phrase is used by the wallet-software that you had). If you had no such back ups, then your only hope is to undelete your wallet-file, using either a professional data recovery service or some sort of undelete tool (in which case try not to *use* the disk before).

Comment: ...but **do not post your *ripple secret* on the internet**. It's secret for a reason! Same goes for seed phrases: they're supposed to be kept secret.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to access those coins again?

If you **wrote down** your *ripple secret* (string of about 28 letters & numbers, starting with *“s”*), then you're OK unless a thief somehow got hold of your *ripple secret*. If your wallet software gave you a *seed phrase* and you **wrote it down**, then you're OK. (You can use your seed phrase to recover your *ripple secret*, either by using the same wallet software or by using tools such as Ian Coleman's mnemonic converter, linked below.)

If you had no such back ups, then your only hope is to undelete your wallet-file, using either a professional data recovery service or some sort of undelete tool (in which case try not to use the disk before). A skilful user of undelete tools might be able to find a *ripple secret* in a damaged relic of your wallet-file, but only if it's not encrypted.

Assuming you recover your *ripple secret*, what next? First of all, **don't post it on the internet**: it's secret for a reason! The same goes for seed phrases. You can use a *ripple secret* to access your coins via several freely available in-browser tools (examples linked below, but some of them are rumoured to misbehave in the Mac web browser Safari.). Whatever tool you use, I strongly recommend that you study it on a computer that's **disconnected from the internet**. If you're using it properly, it will tell you your *address* (string of about 34 letters & numbers, beginning with *“r”*.  It's safe to look up your *address* (beginning with *“r”*) on the internet, *e.g.* [here](https://bithomp.com/), to see if your coins are still there.

- [Ian Coleman's mnemonic seed converter](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/). If you use this, download the page and open it on a computer that's **disconnected from the internet**. Don't expose your seed phrase to the internet!
- [*Bithomp* wallet](https://bithomp.github.io/bithomp-tools/). Read the opening message very carefully before you start (“Introduction”, “Features”, “**Offline mode**”, “Online mode”).
- [Ripplerm's wallet](http://ripplerm.github.io/ripple-wallet/). This one opens up with a demo account, so you have to set it to *your* account by clicking the blue *Change* button & then the *use secretkey* button. It's denominated in drops (1 XRP = 1 million drops), so don't let that confuse you. It has cold-signing functionality, so there's a lot you can do while **safely disconnected from the internet**. Don't try anything with the four pale blue buttons at the foot of the page.
- [Jatchili's minimalistic ripple client](https://jatchili.github.io/minimalist-ripple-client/). Avoid the *rekey account* button.